# Is it right that I need to deploy my lambda in order to test it?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm writing some Python code on AWS Lambda. I haven't used AWS for a few months and I noticed that when I hit the TEST button the test no longer runs on the latest code that I've entered into the Lambda editor, even when I save the code. After some playing around I've found I need to press the DEPLOY button first, then my test runs fine.

Is this right? Surely I should be able to test my code before deploying it. The official AWS documentation doesn't specify that deploying is necessry to run a test.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you need to deploy, you cannot just run python code in mid-air, you can only run deployed code. *"Surely I should be able to test my code before deploying it."* - yes, by having separate infrastructure for dev and prod and not manually playing around with prod code.

Comment: Yes, it is  true

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, The `Deploy` button is updating the code, The `Test` button just Invoke your lambda with a test Event (That can be configured)